# How to prevent Contact Form 7 from clearing form on successfull submission

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to prevent Contact Form 7 WordPress plugin from clearing form on successful submission. I want user to be able to keep editing the form (and possibly to resubmit it again).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a solution. You can just attach an event handler to `reset` event and then do `e.preventDefault()`.

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $( '.my-form form' ).on( 'reset', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
},500)
```

It didn't work without the timeout, but this should be safe enough. Not many users can fill a form in under 0.5 second :-)

Maybe not a perfect solution but it works for my case.

*EDIT: Here is a new version without the setTimeout (thanks to @Jan Myszkier)*

```
$(document).on('reset', '.my-form form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: In that case it will be better to bind it to document, `$(document).on('reset', '.my-form form', function.... ` so you won't have to use setTimeout (because what it does is essentially waiting for the my-form to appear. 
I'm also not so sure binding it on FORM will work, because CF7 code looks like resetting fields, not form, but if that works, then all good :)

Answer (score 0):

In JS `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js` around line 300 there's ajaxSuccess function described with the following piece:

```
            if ( 'mail_sent' == data.status ) {
                $form.each( function() {
                    this.reset();
                } );

                wpcf7.toggleSubmit( $form );
            }
```

which might be just what you're looking for because `this.reset();` resets the field one by one within the form after successful status.

EDIT: Following your information you want to modify the behaviour but not change the plugin, you can use the events that come with CF7.
https://contactform7.com/dom-events/
add `wpcf7submit` watcher to store the data in the localstorage and add another watcher (`wpcf7mailsent` this time ) to write the data back to the form.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the function, but for obvious reasons I don't want to modify the plugin.

Comment: That should work, but I was hoping for a solution where I would actually prevent form from being reset and this solution would be pretty labour intensive as my form has over 20 different field.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such option in CF7. Resetting the form is intuitive and pretty much a standard, so it makes sense for CF7 to always clear it. Changing plugin code is a quick ugly fix, and a nice code is using the events which needs more time for a cleaner effect. I'm afraid those are the only solutions you can get, according to CF7 code and documentation at least.

Comment: I thought the same think, but the solution was actually to think outside the box (in this case outside of the "CF7 box") - I used a JS solution which should work for pretty much any form (including a CF7 form)